# slf4j - what exactly is the compile time binding?

Tags: logging, slf4j

I was trying to understand slf4j binding. I read that it binds to a specific binding implementation during compile time by looking for jars on it's classpath.

But after looking at the code for the `bind()` method in `LoggerFactory` class it appears that it looks for `StaticLoggerBinder` class during runtime.

Relevant Code:

```
private static String STATIC_LOGGER_BINDER_PATH = "org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class";

static Set<URL> findPossibleStaticLoggerBinderPathSet() {
    // use Set instead of list in order to deal with bug #138
    // LinkedHashSet appropriate here because it preserves insertion order during iteration
    Set<URL> staticLoggerBinderPathSet = new LinkedHashSet<URL>();
    try {
        ClassLoader loggerFactoryClassLoader = LoggerFactory.class.getClassLoader();
        Enumeration<URL> paths;
        if (loggerFactoryClassLoader == null) {
            paths = ClassLoader.getSystemResources(STATIC_LOGGER_BINDER_PATH);
        } else {
            paths = loggerFactoryClassLoader.getResources(STATIC_LOGGER_BINDER_PATH);
        }
        while (paths.hasMoreElements()) {
            URL path = paths.nextElement();
            staticLoggerBinderPathSet.add(path);
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Util.report("Error getting resources from path", ioe);
    }
    return staticLoggerBinderPathSet;
}
```

What am I missing here, or where exactly is the confusion arising?

Comment: Have you figured it out meanwhile? I also wonder what does it mean and how could it work.